# Adding A responsive Footer to a website. Footer is on master page and should be shown on every content page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, spacing

How To Add Footer in asp.net Which adjusts automatically with content on the page and the screen size.

I have a Footer on a master page. and I want all the content pages should adapt automatically to the content on the screen or screen size

I have tried.

```
footer {
        background-color: lightgray;
        position: unset;
        left: 0;
        margin-bottom: auto;
        height: 64px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

the added footer on the master page

```
<footer>
        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/wp-content/Images/114x114.png" ImageAlign="Baseline"
            AlternateText="Foodora.com" Height="67px" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Image ID="Image3" ImageAlign="Middle" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/wp-content/Social/facebook_sq.png" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Image ID="Image4" ImageAlign="Middle" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/wp-content/Social/twitter_sq.png" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Image ID="Image5" ImageAlign="Middle" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/wp-content/Social/instagram_sq.png" />
    </footer>
```

but on the page, that has a small amount of content the footer has white blank space ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq0LC.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed  your issue.